# Skip or remove a migration that it's failing on Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm trying to build a basic api for study purposes using Laravel, and is my very very first contact with the framework and php, so i'm facing issues caused by a lack of knowledge on it.

The problem is quite simple: I've create a Users table and i'm trying to create a Houses table right now.

Users and houses depends on a hasMany relationship which one user can have many houses.

But when i've coded the first migration for the houses table creating and ran it, it failed because it said that the method i was using to create the foreign key (foreignIdFor) could not find the user_id. Then i tried to change that method to foreignId() only, but when i tried to run the migrations agains, the edited version of the create houses migration was not used. It kept running the version which used foreignIdFor, and it keeps failing until now.

I've created one other migration for the same purpose, but using foreignId() rightaway, but when i wan php artisan migrate, it stops on the first migration, which is the one that fails everytime.

So i checked migration:status and saw this:

```
  Migration name .............................................. Batch / Status 
  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ............................... [1] Ran 
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table ............... [1] Ran 
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table ......................... [1] Ran 
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table .............. [1] Ran 
  2024_02_24_125752_create_houses_table .............................. Pending 
  2024_02_24_160840_creating_houses_table ............................ Pending
```

`2024_02_24_125752_create_houses_table` is the one that has the method which is failing over and over again.

`2024_02_24_160840_creating_houses_table` is the second i've created that should be ok, but it does not run at all.

I tried many things, including migrate:reset, migrate:refresh, tried to change the date of the first migration so it could be executed after the second one, but nothing happens, because any changes that i make on that file, does not propagate to whatever that keeps and run them.

I also deleted the migration file, but even when it's deleted, somehow the migrate command still runs it

Edit: I forgot to include the migration code, so here it is the very first one, which fails when i run php artisan migrate:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('houses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor('user_id');
            $table->string('house_title');
            $table->string('house_description');
            $table->string('rent_price');
            $table->string('house_pictures');
            $table->string('facilities');
            $table->string('amenities');
            $table->string('rules');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('neighborhood');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('houses');
    }
};
```

And this is the second one, which i don't even know if it's correct:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('houses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->string('house_title');
            $table->string('house_description');
            $table->string('rent_price');
            $table->string('house_pictures');
            $table->string('facilities');
            $table->string('amenities');
            $table->string('rules');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('neighborhood');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        //
    }
};
```

Comment: never had de "pending" status, but usually the problem is your foreign key type is different for your reference field. For example, one is integer and the other is biginteger, or bigincrements, etc. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: What does that migration look like? What is the exact error message you get? I usually use `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` (attention: data will be erased) when developing

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the `2024_02_24_125752_create_houses_table` migration file if it's causing errors?

Comment: @brombeer I did remove the migration file, but somehow even deleted the migrate command keeps running that migration. Also, i edited the post, adding the migration code.

Comment: Try using [php artisan migrate:fresh}(https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#drop-all-tables-migrate) (Warning: this will drop tables/delete data you already entered).